# Does space equal '\0' in C? How can I avoid confusing them?

Tags: c, string

I am writing a function that looks for the first 4 whole numbers separated by a comma in a string.

For example, if the string is:

> 123,4,9.5,av4,3,g1,1,6

the function will extract to a different array the numbers: `123,4,3,1`

Everything works well until I try entering an input with a space in the middle, which is not supposed to be considered as a valid number, but then the loop stops once it bumps into the space. Is there a solution for that?

I'm not allowed to use any other library than `stdio.h`.

Here's my code:

```
int getParameters(int parameters[], int size) {
  char input[100];
  int indexInput = 0, indexParameters = 0;
  int skip = 0, numberSeen = 0, negativeSeen = 0;
  int i = 0;
  scanf("%s", input);

  for ( ; input[indexInput]!= '\0' && indexParameters < size; ++indexInput) {
    if (input[indexInput] == ',' && skip == 1) {
      parameters[indexParameters] = 0;
      skip = 0;
      negativeSeen = 0;
    } else if (input[indexInput] == ',' && negativeSeen == 1 && numberSeen == 1) {
      printf(ERROR);
      return -1;
    } else if (input[indexInput] == ','&& numberSeen == 1) {
      numberSeen = 0;
      indexParameters++;
    } else if (input[indexInput] == ',') {
      continue;
    } else if (input[indexInput] == '-' && skip == 1) {
      continue;
    } else if (input[indexInput] == '-' && numberSeen == 0 && input[indexInput+1] != '-') {
      negativeSeen = 1;
    } else if (input[indexInput] <= '9' && input[indexInput] >= '0') {
      parameters[indexParameters] *= 10;
      parameters[indexParameters] += input[indexInput] - '0';
      numberSeen = 1;
    } else {
      skip = 1;
    }
  }

  if (skip == 1)
    parameters[indexParameters] = 0;
  while (i < 4) {
    printf("%d,", parameters[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "does space equal '\0'?" - obviously not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the [`%s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) format specifier is a bit misleading, it matches a sequence of *non-whitespace* characters. As you can see it's meant to read a word, not the whole string.

Perhaps you want to read a whole line?

Comment: @Ryan: Use `getchar()` to read a single character, `fgets()` to read a line (up to and including the terminating `'\n'`).

Comment: Don't equate *character string* and *sequence of non-whitespace characters*. *character string*, or just *string*, is a sequence of non-zero elements, terminated by a zero.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Right, sry.. I just copied the words from cppref. I can't help that they reused the same specifier from the printf family. It probably should be something like `%w` (word)

Comment: Changed the wording on cppreference.com